# Bounded integral operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

So if $k:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $$\sup_{x}\int |k(x,y)|dy<\infty \ \  \ \sup_{y}\int|k(x,y)|dx<\infty$$
How do you show in this case, $Kf(x)=\int k(x,y)f(y)dy$ is a bounded from $L^2$ to $L^2$. 
Any hints? Clearly $k$ cannot be $L^2$.

Comment: Of course, $k$ **can** be in $L^2$, but it is not necessarily so, as this question of yours (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159693/double-integral-problemapplication-of-fubini-toneli) shows. Finally, this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391701/proof-of-schurs-test-via-youngs-inequality should be helpful. Your question should actually be a special case of that. See also this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_test